# git log --graph no muestra las ramas, solo las muestra como commits sobre master

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Antes, en la institución para la que trabajo, el log graph del git mostraba los commits en cada una de las ramas antes de hacerles merge con master, pero ahora al hacer merge de una rama solamente las muestra como commits sobre master, y no muestra el historial de las ramas
Antes no ocurría así ¿Porqué ahora ocurre esto?
Desde ya muchas gracias

```
* 
* 
* 
* 
* 
* 
* 
* 
* 
* 
* 
* 
* 
* 
*   
|\  
| * 
* | 
|/  
* 
*   
|\  
| *   
| |\  
| | * 
| | * 
| | *  
| | * 
| | * 
| | * 
| | * 
| * |
```

[image: log_graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente git esta haciendo `fast-forward` en vez de hacer un merge. Esto requiere una explicación más detallada. Lo primero que tienes que considerar es que git es **vago**. Si git puede evitarse el trabajo de hacer un merge, lo hará ya que es una operación *costosa*. Y esto que quiere decir?

Supón que empiezas a trabajar en una rama `X` sobre `main`. Y haces, digamos, 3 commits. Si regresas a `main` y le pides a git que mezcle `X`, git lo primero que analiza es si hubo una *bifurcación*. La pregunta es más o menos así: `esta revision en la que estoy parado forma parte de la historia de la rama que se quiere mezclar?` Si la respuesta es **no**, quiere decir que las ramas que estás tratando de mezclar se bifurcaron y hay algo en la historia de donde estás parado en este momento que no pertenece a la historia de la rama que estás pidiendo mezclar y en ese caso git tiene que hacer un *merge*. Si el merge sale bien, se crea una nueva revisión que tiene 2 padres y blah blah... este cuento creo que nos lo sabemos (o por lo menos, eso asumo). Si por el contrario la respuesta es **si** (o sea, `main` no se movió luego de que arrancaste a trabajar en `X`), entonces git en este caso piensa *y para qué voy a hacer un merge si no nos hemos movido de aquí? El resultado final tiene que ser lo que está en `X` así que simplemente pongamos `main` donde está `X` y seamos felices y comamos perdices* y esta operación se llama un `fast-forward`. En este caso no se crea un *merge revision* sino que git mueve `main` a donde está `X`.

Si hay varias ramas que se desarrollan una atrás de la otra, el resultado final es lo que ves en tu chart.

Por último, esto se puede evitar y forzar que git coloque un "merge commit" incluso si no es necesario? Si, claro.... usas `--no-ff`:

```
git merge --no-ff la-otra-rama
```