# Porque no se visualizan ramas de git

Tags: git, github, git-merge

en mi proyecto trabajo con git, creaba ramas y hacia merge y se visualizaban bien pero hace poco al visualizarlas con el código `git log --oneline --graph` se me ve de la siguiente manera, no veo cuando se crea la rama y cuando hace el merge

```
* aa3d0b03 (HEAD -> ramaDOS, origin/main, main) Paso a prod
* a9881067 fix error 5
* 9241cc2c fix error 4
* eaef0281 fix error 3
* fcca38df fix error 2
* 55e669e1 fix error 1
*   99ab3a06 merge de mi primera rama
|\  
| * e01d20fe cambio 5
| * e33462ed cambio 4
| * b735ab1b cambio 3
| * c3f02675 cambio 2
* | ecede8e2 cambio 1
|/  
* 7b71eb26 primer commit
```

los commit 'cambios' se encuentran en una primera rama y los commit 'fix error' se encuentran en una segunda rama pero no se visualiza como tal, sino como si se hubieran hecho los commit en el main, ¿eso a qué se debe?

Comment: añade `--all` para que te coja todas las ramas, con eso te coge solo en la que estas

Comment: No vas a poder ver una historia _fidedigna_ de como se mueven las ramas porque las ramas son meros apuntadores a revisiones... se pueden mover a gusto y gana, igual que se pueden crear y destruir. El merge `99ab3a06` se hizo en `ramaDOS` o en `main`? No hay forma de saberlo a **ciencia cierta**, por ejemplo.

Comment: Adicionalmente si solo  haces `git log`, solo se va a mostrar la historia de la rama/revisión donde estás parado en ese momento. Si quieres ver más ramas, tienes que especificarlas (`git log rama1 rama2`) o, como indica @adrigo, usar `git log --all`.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [git log --graph no muestra las ramas, solo las muestra como commits sobre master](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/432529/git-log-graph-no-muestra-las-ramas-solo-las-muestra-como-commits-sobre-master) || Marqué tu pregunta como duplicada, ya que en otra pregunta se encuentra la respuesta que buscabas. Por cierto, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, lee [ask] y [answer].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

encontré soluciona a mi pregunta en el siguiente post

[git log --graph no muestra las ramas, solo las muestra como commits sobre master](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/432529/git-log-graph-no-muestra-las-ramas-solo-las-muestra-como-commits-sobre-master?rq=1)

Agregando:

```
git merge --no-ff <nombre-rama>
```

Gracias a todos por sus respuestas!